# MoviePy ImageSequenceClip doesn't create a video with transparent background even though the images have transparent background

Tags: python, ffmpeg, moviepy

**Expected Behavior**

I am creating a video using moviepy ImageSequenceClip. The input are the images found on this link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hQ3pfGPMvDAijS4IUcbu5hVy_HmrfCOh?usp=sharing.

All the images are png and have some pixels with the alpha channel set to 0 (the background is transparent).

The created video should keep those background pixels with alpha channel set to 0 (the video background should be transparent).

**Actual Behavior**

The created video is not transparent. The background pixels show their RGB values.

**Steps to Reproduce the Problem**

"images" folder should contain this images: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1hQ3pfGPMvDAijS4IUcbu5hVy_HmrfCOh?usp=sharing.

```
import moviepy.editor as mpy

clip = mpy.ImageSequenceClip("images", fps=24, with_mask=True)
clip.set_opacity(0)
clip.write_videofile("video_test.mp4")
```

**Specifications**

Python Version: 3.7
Moviepy Version: 1.0.3
Platform Name: MacOS Catalina
Platform Version: 10.15.6
I also tried it with Docker using this image and the issue was still there: tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7